# drawable getResources().getIdentifier problem

Tags: android

this is my first time here (I find the website very useful). I'm new to android and I need to find out why I can't dynamically load images in my list view.

I have three arrays of strings:

```
private String lv_arr[]={"News", 
        "Events", 
        "Other"};
private String lv_arr_d[]={"Get the latest news", 
        "Latest events", 
        "Other description here"};
private String lv_arr_icons[]={"news", "events", "other"};
```

My list displays an icon to the left and two lines of text to the right in each list item.
It works ok when I hard code the name of the image (e.g. news).

```
ArrayList <HashMap <String, Object>> users = 
     new ArrayList <HashMap <String, Object>> ();
     int l = lv_arr.length;
     for (int i = 0; i <l; i++) {
     HashMap <String, Object> user = new HashMap <String, Object> ();

     //get icons
     String uri = "drawable/"+lv_arr_icons[i];

     user.put ( "icon", (Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(
             getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName())));
//the above works ok if i set R.drawable.news 
     user.put ( "label", lv_arr[i].toString()); 
     user.put ( "description",  lv_arr_d[i].toString()); 
     users.add (user); 
     }

     String[] names = {"icon", "label", "description"};
     int[] views = {R.id.icon, R.id.label, R.id.description};

     SimpleAdapter saImageItems = new SimpleAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), 
             users,  R.layout.optionslistitem, names, views);
       lv1.setAdapter(saImageItems); //lv1 is my ListView
```

All images are in the drawable folder.
Any ideas why no image loads when i try to pass on their name and get them from resources?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What if you just do this:

```
user.put ( "icon", getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 11):

here is an helper function

```
public static int getDrawable(Context context, String name)
{
    Assert.assertNotNull(context);
    Assert.assertNotNull(name);

    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
            "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```