# Best way to animate programatically created bitmaps in android

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

I have a board game app that creates a lot (hundreds) of bitmaps, and constantly changes them as the game progresses. These bitmaps are created, not loaded from a resource... so they have no R.id to refer to.

I would like to animate some of them, e.g. a bitmap moving from one loction to another when a player taps to move it. What is the best way to do this?

Note, this is 2.1 and the bitmaps are drawn on a canvas via a matrix translate.

Comment: simply... use `setAnimation(yourTranslateAnimation)`

Comment: Not sure about this - surely this works on a view, not a bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this function to get image from drawable folder

```
  private Bitmap getImageBitmap(){
  int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable",
            "a.b.c");
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
    return mBitmap;
   }
```

For set the image , where do you you want>

```
 ImageView imageview01.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("name of bitmap");
```

if you want more about bitmap. then you may try this links.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

[drawable getResources().getIdentifier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276968/drawable-getresources-getidentifier-problem)

[setImageURI / setimagebitmap to fetch image from net and display in image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430351/setimageuri-setimagebitmap-to-fetch-image-from-net-and-display-in-image-view)

Comment: The bitmaps are created programatically, so are not in a drawable folder.

Comment: I ended up adding the bitmaps to imageviews programatically, and then animating the imageviews, which works fine.